# Linq query - List within List

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select a list that contains `Fund.Name` and `List<Investment>`.

```cs
var funds = new List<Fund>
{
    new Fund { Id = 1 , Name = "good" },
    new Fund { Id = 2, Name = "bad" }
};

var investments = new List<Investment>
{
    new Investment { Fund = funds[0], Value = 100 },
    new Investment { Fund = funds[0], Value = 200 },
    new Investment { Fund = funds[1], Value = 300 }
};
```

Then I'm trying to create the query with this:

```cs
var query = from f in funds
            join i in investments
            on f.Id equals i.Fund.Id
            select new { f.Name, i };
```

I wanted something like this:

```
{ Name = good, {{ Id = 1, Value = 100 }, { Id = 1, Value = 200 }}},
{ Name = bad, { Id = 2, Value = 300 }}
```

But I'm getting something like this:

```
{ Name = good, { Id = 1, Value = 100 }},
{ Name = good, { Id = 1, Value = 200 }},
{ Name = bad, { Id = 2, Value = 300 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using GroupJoin.

```
var query = funds.GroupJoin(investments, f => f.Id, i => i.Fund.Id, (f, result) => new { f.Name, result });
```